# Отладка theano updates

Tags: python, pycharm

Есть в `theano` такая штука как `theano.function`, а в ней есть поле `updates`, которое позволяет обновлять параметры созданной функции при каждом вызове. Так вот, есть ли способ посмотреть на результаты этих обновлений? Использую `pycharm`.

Answer (score 2):

Значения можно вывести как и для любой `theano.shared` переменной с помощью  методов `eval`или `get_value`